# What is device administrator supposed to be set to on a smartphone?

Tags: stock-android, permissions, device-administrator

I have an LG smartphone, and I'm curious what my device administrator should be set to. I have two options, one is Android, and the other is the anti-virus program that I'm running. Neither one are check at this time and I'm wondering which one if either should be?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [Device Administrator tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/device-administrator/info)

> **What is "Device Administrator"?**
>
> An app can register as "device administrator", which usually requires the users confirmation. As device administrator, the app gains elevated privileges: it can e.g. define password policies (forbid "swipe-to-unlock", set a minimum password strength, etc.), but also wipe your device on remote commands​

If you don't give the apps the power, they *may not work as expected*. Apps asking for such powers appear under Device Administrator menu you are seeing

- In your case *Android Device Manager* helps you track your device if it is lost (amongst other things) , so enable device admin permission
- Similarly, enable Anti Virus app too, if you want full functionality

Comment: It's helpful to read the tag wiki. You choose the right tag wiki but probably didn't go beyond that :)

Comment: By granting them permissions, they don't control your device completely. They only use the permissions asked by the app